# How to get posts by a certain author in inner loop using outer loop variable or post title WordPress

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

I am working on a WordPress site with staff bio pages.  At the bottom of the page, I would like to include their most recent blog posts (if they have any).  I have an outer loop that pulls the fields from my Advanced Custom Field form and an inner loop where I would like to use their name as an argument for the author.  Right now I am pulling all the blog posts and can't seem to figure out how to use the outer loop post info (in this case I either need the `$name` variable or the title from the outer loop post data. Or to use the last part of the permalink?  Is that possible?

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                $name = get_the_title();
                $position = get_field("position");
                $email = get_field("email");
                $image = get_field("photo");
                $size = "full";
                $bio = get_field("bio");
?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">

    <header id="header" role="banner" class="l-hero-title bio-hero">  
    </header>

    <div id="bio-page" class="l-crew content-wrapper">

        <article
          itemid="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"
          itemscope
          itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"
        >
            <figure>
                <?php if ($image && isset($image['url'])) {
                    echo '<img src="' . esc_url($image['url']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($image['alt']) . '">';
                } ?>
            </figure>
            <h1 class="l-crew-hero__header-name" itemprop="name">
                  <?php echo $name; ?>
            </h1>
            <h2 class="l-crew-hero__header-position" itemprop="hasOccupation">
                  <?php echo $position; ?>
            </h2>

            <div class="l-crew-contact">
                <!-- Email -->
                <a class="l-crew-contact__item email" href="mailto:<?php echo $email; ?>" itemprop="email">
                <?php echo $email; ?></a>
            </div> 

            <section id="content" class="l-crew-bio__wrapper">
                <div class="l-crew-bio">
                    <p><?php echo $bio; ?></p> 
                </div>
            </section>


        </article>   

         <!-- BLOG POSTS SECTION -->
        <section id="posts" class="l-crew__blog-posts-wrapper">
            <div class="l-crew-posts">
                <h3 class="l-crew-posts__hding">
                    Blog Posts </h3>
                <?php
               
                $auth_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_author => $name',
                    'posts_per_page' => 3, 
                ) );

                if ($auth_query->have_posts()) :
                while ($auth_query->have_posts()) :
                    $auth_query->the_post(); 

                    $title = get_the_title();
                    $image = get_field("thumbnail");
                    $date = get_the_date( 'F j, Y' );
                ?>
                <figure class="blog-image c-archive-snippet__img col-md-5">
                    <?php if ($image && isset($image['url'])) {
                        echo '<img src="' . esc_url($image['url']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($image['alt']) . '">';
                    } ?>
                </figure>
                <div class="c-archive-snippet-text-wrapper">
                    <h3 class="c-archive-snippet__title"><?php echo $title ?></h3>
                    <span class="c-archive-snippet__date"><?php echo $date ?></span>
                    <div class="read-more-link-container">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="c-archive-snippet__readmore a-learnmore"><p>Read More</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php 
                    endwhile; 
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            
            </div>
        </section>   
    </div>

</div>            
<?php endwhile; 
?>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Mapping the page to a WordPress user is the best approach. An [ACF User field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/user/) to select the user would give you the author ID, which can then be used easily in a `WP_Query` instance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion.  I finally figured it out.  In this case the author was not necessarily a user.  It was a matter of finding the correct field name for the blog post.  The field name I needed was 'authors' not 'author_name' or 'author'.